# Как правильно сохранять шестнадцатеричный код?

Tags: c++, winapi, hex

Я открываю в моей программе картинку и получаю ее 16-ый код в текстовом поле. Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно сохранить 16-ый код из этого поля, чтобы на выходе получилась та самая картинка. У меня файл сохраняется, но не открывается, пишет неверный формат файла.

Вот как я сохраняю:

```
long length = GetWindowTextLength(hwndbytes); //hwndbytes - дескриптор текстового поля с 16 кодом
TCHAR* data = new TCHAR[length];
GetWindowText(hwndbytes, data, length + 1);
WriteFile(hfile, data, 2*lstrlen(data), &writedBytes, NULL);
CloseHandle(hfile);
```

Выходит так, что я сохраняю 16 код как текст в файл с разрешением *.bmp, но так не катит, подскажите пожалуйста как правильно или ткните носом!

Comment: покажите как текст выглядит

Comment: @Cerbo, какой текст вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Который у вас в текстовом поле

Comment: @Cerbo, вот картинка: http://imgdisk.ru/images/2015/12/13/circle.png, а вот 16 код из моей программы: http://rghost.ru/private/7g59FWyWy/11c361d718838b810908b1f337f3a42f Выходит так, что я открыть могу картинку, а потом сохранить из моей программы ее не могу, она не открывается. 100% не так сохраняю

Comment: @Cerbo, прошу прощения, хостинг картинок выдал картинку в разрешении png, хотя у меня картинка в bmp, на деле я сравнивал 16 код из моей программы с hex редактором и все сходилось. видимо что-то в коде с сохранением

Answer (score 1):

Правильно сохранять не код, а байты. Попытка записать в текстовое поле бинарные данные, а потом выдернуть их через GetWindowText() - не лучшая идея, особенно в TCHAR. Преобразование сырых байтов в текст и обратно приводит, скорее всего, к искажению данных, в результате чего у вас и получается битый файл.